# Living with notifications in a many-tabbed world

Tags: notifications

I like notifications. I also like having many browser tabs open. When my browser is fully zoomed on my main screen, notifications can cover the rightmost tab. When I'm in a busy chat or other notification-heavy situation, they cover it constantly, and I have to move the window to get access to click the tab.

I'm looking for a better way to have my cake and eat it, too – is there some way to have the notifications, but not have this situation? For example, I don't ever really want to interact with the notifications, so if I can click behind them, that would be fine. What do you suggest?

Comment: I hope Apple will reconsider the built in notifications sometime. They absolutely do cover the screen and can be annoying to work around even though they are convenient to see.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) + Pushbullet/iOS/other push notifications.

1. Add every channel you need to IFTTT.
2. Make if %message% then send a note to Pushbullet **OR** to IF Notifications.
3. Enjoy!